# how to grails find withCriteria or condition

Tags: grails, criteria

```
String query='test'
def user = User.withCriteria {
    ilike('firstName', '%'+query+'%')
    or {ilike('lastName', '%'+query+'%')}
    or {ilike('email', '%'+query+'%')}
    }
```

above is the sample  code i need to find  those object  if any one of three of these field(  firstName lastName email ) contains query string
thnks

Comment: Did my sollution work?

Answer (score 1):

Try joining the conditions inside one `or`

```
or {
ilike('firstName', '%'+query+'%'),
ilike('lastName', '%'+query+'%'),
ilike('email', '%'+query+'%')
}
```

You can also turn on SQL debugging to see how your queries get built.

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this way

```
 String query='test'
    def crit = User.createCriteria()
    def user = User.list{
      or{
        ilike('firstName', '%'+query+'%')
        ilike('lastName', '%'+query+'%')
        ilike('email', '%'+query+'%')
        }
      maxResults(1000)
      order("firstName")
     }
```